# readable socket times out on recv

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

I have a 'jobs' server which accepts requests from a client (there are 8 clients sending requests from another machine). The server then submits a 'job' (a 'job' is just an executable which writes a results file to disk), and on a 'jobs manager' thread waits until the job is done. When a job is done it sends a message to the client that a results files is ready to be copied back to the client.

On the main thread I use `select` to read incoming connections from clients, as well as jobs requests:

```
readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, [], [])
```

where `inputs` is a list of accepted connections (sockets), and this list also includes the `server` socket. All sockets are set to non-blocking. To my best understanding, if this call to `select` returns a non-empty `readable`, it means some elements of `inputs` has incoming data waiting to be read.
I am reading data using the following logic (`SIZE` is a constant):

```
for s in readable:
    if s is not server:
        try:
            socket_ok = True
            data = s.recv(SIZE)
        except socket.error as e:        
            print ('ERROR socket error: ' + str(e) )
            socket_ok = False
        except Exception as e:
            print ('ERROR error reading from socket: ' + str(e))
            socket_ok = False
        if not socket_ok:
            # do something
```

I have 2 problems:

- Sometimes I get a `[Errno 110] Connection timed out` exception, and I don't understand why - if I have a readable socket, doesn't it mean it has some data to be read?
- How to deal with this exception - the `#do something` part. I can do a 'cleanup' - delete the running jobs which were requested by the timed-out socket, and remove the dead socket from the list. But I have no way of letting the client know that it should stop waiting for these jobs' results. Ideally I would like to reconnect somehow, because the jobs themselves keep running and produce results which I don't want to throw away.

**EDIT** I realized now that the jobs manager thread also have access to the sockets via a `Queue` instance - if a job is finished, the thread sends a 'job done' message through the relevant socket - so maybe the `send` and `recv` methods of the same socket cause some kind of race condition? But anyway, I don't see how this can cause a 'connection timed out' error.

Comment: Try reading the details here: https://pymotw.com/2/select/

Comment: @ReutSharabani, I read it and actually my code is based on it. But you can see in my code that the exception is thrown when reading from a socket in the `readbale` list, and the link you mentioned states `All of the sockets in the readable list have incoming data buffered and available to be read` - so this does not explain the problem I have

Answer (score 0):

A solution that was just a guess and seems to work: On the client side, I am using a blocking `recv` method to get message from the server that the job is done. Since a job can take a long time (e.g if the cluster running the jobs is low on resources), I guessed that maybe the socket waiting was the cause of the time-out. So instead of using `recv` in blocking mode, I use it with time-out of 5 seconds, so I can send a dummy message to the server every 5 seconds to keep the connection alive until a message is received. Now I don't get the exception (on the server side) any more.